# Best way to change an integer field in a compiled 1.6 Java class with no source

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, decompiling, bytecode-manipulation

A class file that was compiled with java 1.6 settings has two fields which I need to set to higher values.

```
private Integer days = 7;
private Integer running = 30;
```

unfortunately, I don't have access to the code of the correct revision anymore, and only posess the class file.

Here is what I already tried: I've been toying around with BCEL,asm and javassist, but this doesn't seem to be trivial at all. I couldn't find a suitable bytecode editor either (jbe looks really confusing,class editor doesn't show the value of the Integer objects). The Eclipse Bytecode Class file viewer crahes when trying to save. Using a hex editor to manipulate the values is out of the question since they will have more digits than now. I also looked into javap and recompiling it with jasmin - which doesn't seem possible.

So ultimately - please, oh please - does anybody have a good example how this can be done in any imaginable way?

Comment: do you have just a single stand-alone class file or is it part of a jar?

Comment: Is setting them at runtime using reflection an option?

Comment: It's just a class file. No jars. Reflection is not an option. It has to be done on the class file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried decompiling, editing, then recompiling?  As far as I know, JD is working pretty well.

http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

Comment: yes, that's what I recommended too. I use it in eclipse and it works pretty well

Comment: Using a regular decompiler would mean, that I'd have to have access to all the dependencies too, to recompile it. Sadly I don't.

Answer (score 2):

You can set them using reflection like the earlier answer points out. Here is an example:

```
public class TestSetPrivateFields extends TestCase {

    public void testSetFields() throws Exception {
        Legacy legacyObj = new Legacy();
                    // get the fields using reflection
        Field[] fields = {
                          legacyObj.getClass().getDeclaredField("days"),
                          legacyObj.getClass().getDeclaredField("running")
                          }; 
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Integer value = (Integer) field.get(legacyObj);
            // set their value
            field.set(legacyObj, value+1);
        }

        Legacy expected = new Legacy();
        assertEquals(expected.getDays()+1, legacyObj.getDays()+0);
        assertEquals(expected.getRunning()+1, legacyObj.getRunning()+0);
    }

    public static class Legacy {
        private Integer days = 7;
        private Integer running = 30;

        public Integer getDays() {return days;}
        public Integer getRunning() { return running;}
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 - thanks, didn't have time earlier to post an example. Also for the completeness of your answer.

Comment: Since that would have to be done at runtime, I won't be able to use it. Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you don't have the source.

I wouldn't go through all that pain.  If it's difficult, perhaps it's a sign that you shouldn't do it.

I'd rather use [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad), de-compile the .class file, make my change, and get on with it.

Comment: Simple. The old version of the code wasn't versioned. The old programmers are gone. No chance to go back ever.

Answer (score 0):

This looks Promising:

http://classeditor.sourceforge.net/

Comment: As I said, class editor aparrently doesn't let me change the values of an Integer object - or is just too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JD-Core](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/). The plugin for eclipse allowed me to peek into some undocumented library to help me better understand it. It doesn't work on all compiled java classes, but it pretty much opened everything so far for me.

Comment: Thanks, but viewing the sourcecode is not the issue. It's being able to manipulate the class file. And after decompiling JD Core isn't able to recompile without all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would us [ASMifier](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial.html) (or the Eclipse Bytecode Outline) to produce the java class that when run with `java -cp asm-all.jar MyAsmClass` would produce the new version of the necessary class. The values in question have to be updated in all constructors and will be in a `visitLdcInsn()` call.

Comment: Interesting solution. Manipulating the bytecode seems straightforward. But the commandline above doesn't recompile the asm file back to a class file - is asm able to do that?

Comment: You just compile it with javac and run the resulting class. It will generate the class in question.

Answer (score 0):

Using a bytecode editor is extremely easy. Either the field will have an associated DefaultValue attribute or you'll find in  ()V something like:

```
aload_0
bipush 7
invokestatic java/lang/Integer#valueOf (I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
putfield Blah#days Ljava/lang/Integer;
```

It should be clear what to fix here.